# What template does the Fooman Email Attachments use for Print

Tags: magento-1.7, template

Fooman Email Attachments extension gives you the option to print from the order page before an invoice is actually created (exactly what I need). I'm curious though what template (if any) it uses when I click the "print" button.

I tried looking in the documentation for the extension but found nothing. http://cdn.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/UserManual-FoomanEmailAttachments.pdf

I want to add some of what shows up on the PDF when you click PRint from the order summary page.

Extension URL:

http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento-extension-email-attachments.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the "Print" button in the admin order view page.
That has no template, it uses `Zend_Pdf` to generate the pdf file.
The action that handles this is `Fooman_EmailAttachments_Admin_OrderController::printAction()` and the method that generates the PDF is `Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_Order::getPdf`.

Answer (score 1):

As Marius pointed out the Pdf generated is based on Zend_Pdf. The class that provides the pdf can be found here

```
/app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php
```

and is based on the default Magento Invoice Pdf

```
class Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{
```

Similar to how the default pdfs work there is no template and if you want to customise it you would need to copy the class to your local folder and edit it there. Some tips for this can be found in the [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf#dokuwiki__top).

The one thing that I can't yet explain is your comment

> I want to add some of what shows up on the PDF when you click PRint
>   from the order summary page.

since when both are created with Email Attachments they have the same content. My current guess here is that you are using a separate extension which also adds a custom order pdf. Or were you referring to the frontend customer facing order summary?